# Change destination author link

Tags: plugins, php, functions, author

It's possible change the destination of the normal author link to a post page or other link inside the website?

I have found this answer but needed do buy php code. Is possible found easier way, form the users page in the back-end?

```
function wpd_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ){
    return 'http://my.blog.tld/';
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpd_author_link', 20, 3 );
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can place filters and hooks in the functions.php file. That file runs on every page load.

Answer (score 4):

To only edit the link associated with authors, in the functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'new_author_link', 10, 1 );

function new_author_link( $link ) {      
    $link = 'http://newlink.com/'; //set this however you wish

    return $link; //after you've set $link, return it to the filter              
}
```

If you're looking to do something like set each author's link to an existing wp page of the same name (***untested example***):

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'new_author_link', 10, 3 );
function new_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ) {

     $page = get_page_by_path( $author_nicename );

     if ($page) { 

         $page = $page->ID;
         $link = get_permalink( $page ); 
     }
     else {
        $link = ''; //some default value perhaps
     }
     return $link;
}
```

More from WP Codex on [Filtering the Author](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/author_link)

More from WP Codex on [Filters in general.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

---

### For your updated example:

If you're trying to redirect all author links to `home_url( 'link' )`

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'new_author_link', 10, 1 );

function new_author_link( $link ) {         
    $link = home_url( 'link' ); //set this however you wish

    return $link; //after you've set $link, return it to the filter                
}
```

If you're trying to achieve some other conditional if/else:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'new_author_link', 10, 1 );

function new_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ) {         
    //send author with id one to home link
    if ($author_id == '1') {
         $link = home_url( 'link' ); //set this however you wish
    }
    //send all other authors to some other link
    else {
        $link = 'http://sitename.com/some-other-url/';
    }

    return $link; //after you've set $link, return it to the filter                
}
```

Comment: Hi @hwl. Thank you. This work but if I have 1 author. If i have more then one how I can redirect all people to the specific page. I try to use `$author_nicename`  but dosen't work.

Comment: Try the first solution. What you set $link to should apply to all author links in that case.

Comment: I've added two examples based on your update.

Answer (score 0):

At moment i have done in this way:

add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_multi_author_link', 10, 2 );
function my_multi_author_link( $url, $user_id ) {

```
if ( 1 === $user_id )
    return home_url( 'link' );

return $url;
```

}

add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_multi_author_link_2', 10, 2 );
function my_multi_author_link_2( $url, $user_id ) {

```
if ( 5 === $user_id )

    return home_url( 'link' );

return $url;
```

}

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, but even if you were to approach it this way, that could be combined into one filter.